# How to express all files/directories at the extra -exec option of `find` command?

Tags: regex, command-line, find

I have a task to copy all files from multiple directories with special names to a target directory.

So I build this directory to test my command. The test directory tree looks like:

```
.
├── dir1
│   └── file1
└── test
```

My intended command to mv all files from dir1 to test is:

```
find . -type d -name "*dir*" -exec mv {}/* test \;
```

Then I got:

```
mv: rename ./dir1/* to test/*: No such file or directory
```

I guess this is because in that extra -exec expression, the command didn't treat the * as a wildcard.

So I did:

```
find . -type d -name "*dir*" -exec mv {}/file1 test \;
```

Which successfully moved file1 to test.

But the point is, I need to now the expression for all files so that I can accomplish this file transfer work.

How should I express that in the `find -exec` command group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are intending only to move the files from any `dir*` (* indicating `dir` followed by any additional characters as a wildcard), you would want to use the `-type f`, meaning `files`:

```
find dir* -type f -name "*" -exec mv {} test \;
```

`-type d` indicates to `find` that you are specifying a directory.